# HTTP 403 Forbidden - Custom Login Page

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

My site has been configured to use forms based authentication. A user can login successfully if the default login page is used.

I have created a custom login page (Application Page) which inherits from IdentityModelSignInPageBase. I have deployed my solution to the site.

I get a HTTP 403 Forbidden when going to the site. How do I configure the right permissions?

Answer (score 1):

403 Forbidden normally means some kind of fault that's not permissions based (that'd be 401 Unauthorized).

What I've done for this in the past is have a look at the default login page and see what it inherits, and just make sure your custom one inherits the same class.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check in this (and many other cases) is the Log files.

- It can be any error, e.g. your Login page is failing and trying to
  display an error page.
- Anonymous users not having access to the master page.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take the reference of the below site. It worked well for me without issues.

http://tomaszrabinski.pl/wordpress/2011/06/23/sharepoint-2010-custom-login-page/

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this as well on my WebApp. A restart of the User Synchronization Service resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an answer too late, however for future users as myself who might be looking for the same answer. 
If you have a custom login page that is using the Default MasterPage, then you might run into this issue.

Option 1 is to give anonymous users access to the site (Visit Central Admin, click "Authentication Providers" on the "Application Management > Manage web applications" page; select the zone and select Anonymous Access checkbox. Also give the Anonymous Users permissions for Lists and Libraries) -> This might not be what you want though.

Option 2 is to change the masterpage that is loaded for your custom page.

You can do this:
Replace

```
DynamicMasterPageFile=”~masterurl/default.master”
```

with

```
MasterPageFile=”~/_layouts/customlogin/simple.master”
```

To save you the hustle, you could adopt the page from
https://github.com/dipongkor/FBA-Custom-Login-Page

It's for SharePoint 2013, but we've been able to use the same on SharePoint 2016  by creating a custom page and porting the SharePoint elements.

(Notice how the masterpage used on that is the error.master :) )